# creating custom scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a custom scrollbar using just pure JavaScript and I'm having problem with making the pointer to reach the end of the scrollbar when I reach the bottom of the page. Is there any way to do that without using jQuery?

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4msxo2h/)

#### HTML:

```
<div id="scroll-bar"></div>
<div id="pointer"></div>
<div class="test">first</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test">middle</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test">final</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var scrollBar = document.getElementById("scroll-bar");
var pointer = document.getElementById("pointer");
for (var i = 0; allDivs[i] != undefined; i++) {
  var last = i;
}
var pageHeight = allDivs[last].offsetHeight + allDivs[last].offsetTop;
pointer.style.top = "7%";

function setPosition(e) {
  var pos = e.screenY * 86;
  var move = pos / scrollBar.offsetHeight - 10;
  if (move > 7 && move < 89) {
    pointer.style.top = move + "%";
  }
  var scrollValue = move * pageHeight / 100;
  window.scrollTo(0, scrollValue);
}

function resetPosition() {
  scrollBar.removeEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
  pointer.removeEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
}
scrollBar.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  pointer.addEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
  pointer.addEventListener('mouseup', resetPosition);
  scrollBar.addEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
  scrollBar.addEventListener('mouseup', resetPosition);
});
scrollBar.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  setPosition(event);
});
pointer.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
  pointer.addEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
  pointer.addEventListener('mouseup', resetPosition);
  scrollBar.addEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
  scrollBar.addEventListener('mouseup', resetPosition);
});
body.addEventListener("mousewheel", function () {
  scrollBy(0, -window.event.wheelDelta);
});
body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", function (e) {
  scrollBy(0, e.detail * 50);
});
```

#### CSS:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.test {
    height: 100px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
}
#scroll-bar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0%;
    top: 7%;
    width: 3%;
    height: 86%;
    background-color: red;
}
#pointer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0.5%;
    top: 7%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 4%;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong. To calculate scroll dimensions (height/width, offset, etc...) there is no need to get last DIV offset, because it can be positined absolutely and won't affect scrollable height. Better to use scrollHeight (or scrollWidth for horizontal scrollbar) property and check if its value bigger than actual block/document height. To calculate scrollbar size, you should use next formula: scrollbar height = document height * document height / scrollable height. For example, your document height is 200 px, scrollable height 1000px, so, scrollbar height should be 40px.

Comment: This was example of scrollbar that depends on scrollable height. Besides this you will have to make lots of things. Even with jQuery it's not an easy task, and jQuery helps to make your code simplier. Advice: try to complete your scrollbar with jQuery first, then you can change it to not use jQuery.